# Xcode log message: nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networking, wifi

I am using ConnectSDK in my IOS app to cast media to devices connected to the Wi-Fi network. But when testing searching devices on my iPhone, I get Xcode log message - nehelper sent invalid result code [1] for Wi-Fi information request. This message starts to appear every second after "let discoveryManager = DiscoveryManager()" line. Thus, no device can be found, the search will be eternal.

```
import UIKit
import ConnectSDK
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

class ViewController: UIViewController, DevicePickerDelegate, DiscoveryManagerDelegate, ConnectableDeviceDelegate {
    
    func connectableDeviceReady(_ device: ConnectableDevice!) {
    }
    
    func connectableDeviceDisconnected(_ device: ConnectableDevice!, withError error: Error!) {
    }
    
    func devicePicker(_ picker: DevicePicker!, didSelect device: ConnectableDevice!) {
    }
    
    func devicePicker(_ picker: DevicePicker!, didCancelWithError error: Error!) {
    }
    
    func discoveryManager(_ manager: DiscoveryManager!, didFind device: ConnectableDevice!) {
        print("Device found: \(device.friendlyName)")
    }
    
    func discoveryManager(_ manager: DiscoveryManager!, didLose device: ConnectableDevice!) {
        print("Device lost: \(device.friendlyName)")
    }

    func discoveryManagerDidStopDiscovery(_ manager: DiscoveryManager!) {
        print("Device search ended")
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let discoveryManager = DiscoveryManager()
        
        discoveryManager.delegate = self
        
        let devicePicker = discoveryManager.devicePicker()
        
        devicePicker?.delegate = self
        devicePicker?.show(self)
        
        if let currentSSID = getCurrentSSID() {
            print("Current network: \(currentSSID)")
        } else {
            print("Not connected")
        }
        
        discoveryManager.startDiscovery()
    }
    
    func getCurrentSSID() -> String? {
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as? [String] {
            for interface in interfaces {
                if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                    if let ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String {
                        return ssid
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

I tried requesting Core Location permission, but even when authorized, the behaviour is the same. Also, I tried retrieving SSID of the current Wi-Fi network with this function:

```
    func getCurrentSSID() -> String? {
        if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as? [String] {
            for interface in interfaces {
                if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                    if let ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String {
                        return ssid
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

But it turns out that interfaces contains only one - "en0" and CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as CFString) returns nil, so getCurrentSSID() returns nil. Maybe this is the problem.

Also, I don't have Apple Developer Account, not sure if it is mandatory to use Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hey Vladimir, did you solve this?

Comment: Hey, no, unfortunately, still struggling